# External Credential - merge parameters in callout body

Tags: apex, namedcredentials

So I have created a secure endpoint named credential with an external credential. The external credential has 1 principal with two properties, client_id and client_secret. Now I can't find any way to actually access the values from APEX.

I have tried pretty much everything to reference them `{!$Credential.client_id}`, `{!$Credential.external_credential.client_id}` but nothing seems to be valid.

In other words how can I reference the custom attributes so that I can forge my http body? Or is there a general concept that I'm not getting, around these new types of named credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify if you checked the `Allow Formulas in HTTP Body`

[image: Allow Formulas in HTTP Body]

Also, if you are mapping the External Credential to a Permission Set

[image]

Then, when you set the named credential as the endpoint and use the `{!$Credential.external_credential.client_id}`, this will be replaced at sending time

Comment: I had both allowed formulas and the permission set but it wasn't working. Until I've copy paste your formula reference, which I swear had tried before and didn't work. Seems like everything is fine now and I was able to construct the body properly

Comment: Can this done in the the endpoint? for example abc=`{!$Credential.external_credential.customparameter}`

The end result would be callout:namedcredential?abc=xyz